# How to use i18next to translate with Anuglar plugin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, internationalization, i18next

I'm using i18next with the plugin https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next. with the angular directive, it's supposed to display "test" and "this is a test" on the page. But it shows "home.title" and "home.content". checked the console, json files are loaded properly, correct content can be displayed if I use javascript DOM.

my json file:

```
{
    "home":{
        "title": "test",
        "content": "this is a test"
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="home">
<h1 ng-i18next="home.title"></h1>
<p ng-i18next="home.content"></p>
</div>
```

script:

```
angular.module('jm.i18next')
.config(['$i18nextProvider',function($i18nextProvider){
  window.i18next.use(window.i18nextXHRBackend);

  $i18nextProvider.options = {
    debug: true,
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
    }
  };
}]);

angular.module('myApp', ['jm.i18next']).controller('myCtrl',['$scope', '$i18next',function($scope, $i18next){
}])
```

Here is the info from console, I don't know what the last error is:

- i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translation for language
  en Object {home: Object}
- i18next.min.js:2 i18next: languageChanged en
- i18next.min.js:2 i18next: initialized Object {debug: true, ns:
  Array[1], defaultNS: Array[1], fallbackLng: Array[1], fallbackNS:
  false…}
- ng-i18next.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: i.lng is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just double checked and looks like `i18next` module was upgraded to the newer version, so there are following options:

```
{
  compatibilityAPI: 'v1',
  compatibilityJSON: 'v1',
  // ...old options from v1
}
```

which should be used for `i18next` to have `ng-i18next` plugin worked.

**P.S:** As an advice, I'd suggest you to use [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) plugin instead of this one, but it's totally up to you.

Comment: I tried {{ home.title }} and {{ home.content }}, then there's nothing on the page

Comment: @VincentFu and yes, misunderstood, sorry. You may keep it without curly braces.

Comment: Yes it's working with the compatibility flags, thanks @OlegMeleshko